# cmdline argument parsing using tcl?

Tags: tcl, cmdline-args

I am trying to pass the parameters to Spirent test center tool  using command line arguments, where I am passing slots, ports, frame size and load. I want to store the Slots and ports in array, where number of ports are dynamic. 
I tried simple code with cmdline which can handle fixed ports

```
package require cmdline

set parameters {
    {s.arg ""   "Slot"}
    {p.arg ""   "Port"}
    {l.arg "100"   "Load"}
    {f.arg "256"   "Framesize"}
    {debug      "Turn on debugging, default=off"}
}
#set option(l) 100
set usage "- A simple script to demo cmdline parsing"

if {[catch {array set options [cmdline::getoptions ::argv $parameters $usage]}]} {
    puts [cmdline::usage $parameters $usage]
} else {
    parray options
}
#puts [array get options]
puts $options(l)
puts $options(f)
```

script Output:

```
C:\Tcl\bin>tclsh opt.tcl -s 1 -f 128
options(debug) = 0
options(f)     = 128
options(l)     = 100
options(p)     =
options(s)     = 1
100
128
```

Here I would like to pass all the ports for each slots onetime ,

```
tclsh opt.tcl -s 1 2 -p 11 12 13 14 -f 256 -l 100
```

Where slots are 1 and 2 and ports in each slot are 11,12,13,14 and need to create array of slot and ports. Could you please suggest some method to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
tclsh opt.tcl -s "1 2" -p "11 12 13 14" -f 256 -l 100
```

It works for me under Windows 10, at least. The thing is that the lists of slots and ports need to be one value each: the quotes ensure that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following method with some corrections:

```
     set arglen [llength $argv]
     while {$index < $arglen} {
     set arg [lindex $argv $index]
     #puts $arg
     switch -exact -- $arg {
          -s {
        set args($arg) [lindex $argv [incr index]]
        set slot($y) $args($arg)
        incr y
            }
        -p {
           set args($arg) [lindex $argv [incr index]]
            set port($z) $args($arg)
            incr z
            }
           -l {
                 set args($arg) [lindex $argv [incr index]]
                global Load
                set Load $args($arg)
                }
            -f {
                set args($arg) [lindex $argv [incr index]]
                set frameLength $args($arg)
                }   

          }
            incr index
          }
```

Command to run:

```
           C:\Tcl\bin>tclsh l1.tcl -s 1 -p 11 -p 12 -l 10 -f 1
```